# Directory does not exists (Lotus Notes)

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm trying to get all the database on my server. But specifying my server name in `getDbDirectory()` parameter as **NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM** gives me a error.

> Directory NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM!! does not exist

it always add two exclamation mark at the end. I tried also as server name and mail file adding **.nsf** format at the end of mail file. `NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM!!data0\126\1000031540.nsf` also gives me the same error.

Snipper code below:

```
Session session = null;
Database db = null;
DbDirectory dir = null;

try
{
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    session = NotesFactory.createSession();
    System.out.println("User = " + session.getUserName());
    dir = session.getDbDirectory("NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM");

    System.out.println(dir.getName());

    db = dir.getFirstDatabase(DbDirectory.DATABASE);

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Title: " +db.getTitle());
    }
    while(dir.getNextDatabase() != null);

}
catch(NotesException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error always points out to the `db = dir.getFirstDatabase(DbDirectory.DATABASE);` because `dir.getFirstDatabase(DbDirectory.DATABASE)` expects .nsf file even I specify the file format. Any reasons why I got this error?

Comment: How is this code running? As an agent? A standalone Java program? Are you using Notes.jar or NCSO.jar? Have you verified that you have access to the server? (I.e., what happens if you try session.getDatabase("NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM","Names.nsf"?)

Comment: Hi! @RichardSchwartz I'm running this in a standalone Java program and using Notes.jar. I tried to verify the access using `database.isOpen()` method but it won't authenticate me. But if I used the server and file address of my Workspace it really works well.

Comment: I'm unclear on something: did you try database.isOpen() on the DB object that you are retrieving via dir.getFirstDatabase()? Or did you try my recommendation of checking what happens if you do session.getDatabase("NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM","Names.nsf" in order to see if you have access to the server?

Comment: Also, using Using the same ID and password that you are providing when createSession() prompts you, are you able to access the server NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM in the Notes client?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Yes I also tried `session.getDatabase("NALLN304/40/LLN/IBM","Names.nsf")` and used `isOpen()` method but it this won't authenticate me.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I tried server and file when providing for my `createSession()` but I cannot access the server. My file location system is on the Server.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your ID is not authenticating with the server. You need to take the output from this line:

```
System.out.println("User = " + session.getUserName());
```

And take it to your server administrators, ask why it is not being allowed to access the server, and ask them to assist you either by granting the necessary permissions or by giving you another ID that you can use.

Comment: I'm getting my username. But the server and file won't authenticate.I'll try to contact my administrators for able to get all my database in Lotus Notes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for server connection errors. Even if the server has to connect to itself. Faced the same problem. The server gave an error because it did not find a route for the connection. Added a new connection for the server to itself and everything was fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).